# On constants that maintain proportionality

Tags: newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, si-units

I do not consider my knowledge on mechanics higher than average, and average is perhaps as good as it gets; however, I ask this question to better my knowledge on the way physics has been modeled. I don't fully understand the way proportionality constants are used, let me explain. A fairly elementsry relation comes to mind:

$$F =G   {m_1 \times m_2 \over r^2}.$$

Here, $G$ is a constant value that indicates the fact that $F$ is in a multiplicative relation to  $ m_1 \times m_2 \over r^2$. I don't quite understand the greater meaning behind this. Why does the universe work this way? Why must $F$ be in a geometrical proportion to $ m_1 \times m_2 \over r^2$, why didn't people think it was perhaps an arithmetical proportion? Were these facts acquired experimentally? Furthermore, and more importantly, why is it the precise value of $G ≈ 6.67 \times 10^{–11}$? Why did the universe choose this number? Or is it perhaps only a placeholder before the actual relation between $F$ and $ m_1 \times m_2 \over r^2$ is found?

Comment: You can choose units in which $G=1$. Relativists routinely do this. $G$ has a weird value in SI units because SI units are weird and have no relationship to nature.

Comment: You can read about [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) in which Coulomb’s Law has no proportionality constant and is just $q_1q_2/r^2$.

Comment: Tip: Only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: By "arithmetical proportion", do you mean changing $F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$ to $F=G+\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$? Apart from the dimensional analysis concerns, that would mean even with no gravitating mass there'd still be a force.

Comment: Combining Galileo's falling objects having the same acceleration with Newton's second law gave multiplicative proportionality for one of the masses.  Kepler's laws of planetary motion (in particular the third) gave multiplicative proportionality for $\frac1{r^2}$.  Newton's third law then gave multiplicative proportionality for the other mass. So it was all multiplicative, with a multiplicative constant of proportionality.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I don't quite understand the greater meaning behind this. Why does the universe work this way?

Join the club, friend.  Physics can only supply the "why" to the point of deriving general laws from experiment.  If you want the *philosophical* "why", or meaning, then you're straying into metaphysics or even theology.

> Why must F be in a geometrical proportion to m1×m2r2, why didn't people think it was perhaps an arithmetical proportion? Were these facts acquired experimentally?

That expression is a best fit to observed phenomenon.  In this case, it is a consequence of Newton* fitting Kepler's laws of planetary motion and Galileo's laws of forces and acceleration to one common framework.

Kepler and Galileo, in turn, based their work on the observations of others.

> Furthermore, and more importantly, why is it the precise value of G≈6.67×10–11?

It is not.  That is the [*approximate* value of the gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) *in the units of* $\mathrm{N m^2 / kg^2}$, or in English, Newton-meters squared per kilograms squared.

The number would be different if the units were in pound-force-foot squared per slug squared, or dyne-centimeter squared per gram squared, or other combinations of force times length squared divided by mass squared.

More importantly -- physics doesn't say *why* that number is what it is (or, if you want to use a system where it's not fundamental, why the constants from which it is derived are, themselves, what they are).

> Why did the universe choose this number?

1. We don't know.
2. Just the wording of that question suggests that it is theological, not physical.
3. There are physicists who are working on answering this, but they haven't yet come up with falsifiable theories -- just suppositions that fit current data, but don't seem to make predictions.**

> Or is it perhaps only a placeholder before the actual relation between F and m1×m2r2 is found?

Every scientific theory is only a placeholder, until some better or more accurate expression is found.  When that more accurate expression is found*** then it, too, will just be a placeholder, until some better or more accurate expression is found.

---

* I think it's uniquely Newton -- although I wouldn't be surprised if there weren't some Indian or Chinese mathematician who worked out the same thing at some point.

** With apologies to anyone who's a passionate believer in one anthropomorphic principle or another.

*** In the case of Newtonian gravity, see [General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity).

Comment: I feel like there must be something more than "the formula is a best fit to observed phenomenon". Even in a thought experiment, a different gravitation law like G=(m1m2)^2/r^2 is self-inconsistent, as a piece matter would exert different forces depending on how you mentally divided it. An item with mass M would exert a different gravitational force from an identical version with a fracture down the middle dividing it into two items of mass M/2, but they are effectively the same object. We need no observations to determine that the formula for G can't take this form.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie But that only demonstrates that there is a formula that would be self-inconsistent as a gravitation law. That doesn't mean that all possible alternate formulas for gravitation are self-inconsistent. (And to be completely fair, to a degree self-consistency could potentially be argued itself as an observed property of the universe rather than an axiomatic one.)

Comment: @JustinHilyard It demonstrates much more that, namely that the force must be  proportional to the mass, not any other non-linear relationship between the two. It doesn't just rule out this one possible relationship, it rules out *everything except* a linear relationship. I wonder if we need to "observe" the fact of self-consistency, we seem to be assuming it by the premise that the gravitational force between two objects can be uniquely defined by a formula. If we can even talk about "a" uniquely defined gravity force between objects it must be a linear relationship between force and mass.

Answer (score 8):

1. The proportionality constant is woven into the universe. There is no reason it should be any particular number- except that if it were different from what it is, we wouldn't be here to notice it (see *anthropic principle*).
2. Why the *product* of the two masses? This is what you get algebraically if you break up each gravitating body into teeny little bits, and then sum up the contributions from each teeny little bit attracting every other teeny little bit.
3. Why the *1/(distance squared)* effect? this is what you get geometrically if the field that mediates gravitational attraction is being propagated into 3-dimensional space.

Comment: No offense, but the "anthropic principle" is just a poor way of saying "I don't know.". Before we had quantum mechanics the structure of the periodic table was more or less a complete mystery. With quantum mechanics it became a high school triviality. I would be very surprised if nobody can come up with a first principles calculation of all physical constants, ever. I think the more important aspect is the third point... which only holds if there are no hidden dimension. This has been much discussed (and experimentally tested) lately. I think it opens up a whole new way of looking at physics.

Comment: @FlatterMann Its hard for me to imagine a derivation of physics from 'first principles' that doesn't contain some arbitrary choices (e.g. a choice of dimensions, algebras, symmetries, etc.). Any arbitrary choice, even if it's mathematical in nature, would keep the anthropic principle alive.

Comment: @cms Relativity is not an arbitrary choice. It's an observation that was already made by Galileo. So are the symmetries of spacetime. We can derive an awful lot from those two observations alone (some will say that we can derive most of physics), we just can't derive all of physics in a unique way. We are left with a (large) number of possible choices how a relativistic and metric world can look like. This means we are still lacking, at least, one more clue. I can't tell you what that clue will be, but I am fairly certain that it won't be something outrageously more complex than the first two.

Comment: There are some constants that are "woven into the universe" and have anthropic consequences, like the strength of the weak force and the curvature of the universe. But G is not like this, it's just a number used to convert between different units on the left and right sides of the equation.

Answer (score 7):

People thought about a lot of different ways how this "could" work before they had experimental and observational data that shows "how it actually works", but if we do the Cavendish experiment or one of its modern successors, then we find that gravity obeys Newton's equation at the bench scale within the limits of experimental precision (and it still does that in the latest iteration of so called "post-Newtonian gravity" searches). If we observe planetary movement coarsely, like Copernicus and Kepler and Tycho Brahe did, then we find, again, that gravity obeys such a law at the scale of the solar system. OTOH, if we observe the motion of Mercury over a long time with much better instruments than the ones these gentlemen had and we correct for the gravitational influences of all other planets, then something is "off". Mercury shows a Perihelion movement that is not explained correctly by this formula. And that's why Einstein invented general relativity... to explain an effect that Newtonian gravity can not explain. So in the end this is simply how science works: we formulate a hypothesis that explains our observations, then we refine our observations and we often find that our earlier explanation was "good enough" initially, but that it's not "good enough" anymore for our refined data.